# Montar combinações possíveis

Tags: c#

Tenho as seguintes classes:

```
public class Categoria
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public bool Primeiro { get; set; }
}

public class Opcao
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public virtual Categoria CategoriaProxima { get; set; }
    public virtual Categoria Categoria { get; set; }
    public bool Ultima { get; set; }
}
```

Exemplo de dados:

```
Categoria                           Opcao

Escolha o que deseja tratar         Rugas
Escolha o que deseja tratar         Manchas
Escolha o que deseja tratar         Olheiras
Escolha o que deseja tratar         Fotoproteção
Escolha o que deseja tratar         Flacidez

Selecione seu tipo de pele          Pele Normal
Selecione seu tipo de pele          Pele Oleosa
Selecione seu tipo de pele          Pele Seca
Selecione seu tipo de pele          Pele Extra Seca

Selecione seu tipo de ruga          Rugas Finas
Selecione seu tipo de ruga          Rugas Médias
Selecione seu tipo de ruga          Rugas Profundas

Selecione seu fototipo              Fototipo 1
Selecione seu fototipo              Fototipo 2
Selecione seu fototipo              Fototipo 3
Selecione seu fototipo              Fototipo 4
```

Gostaria de obter o seguinte resultado:

```
Rugas - Pele Normal - Rugas Finas - Fototipo 1
Rugas - Pele Normal - Rugas Finas - Fototipo 2
Rugas - Pele Normal - Rugas Finas - Fototipo 3
Rugas - Pele Normal - Rugas Finas - Fototipo 4

Rugas - Pele Normal - Rugas Médias - Fototipo 1
Rugas - Pele Normal - Rugas Médias - Fototipo 2
Rugas - Pele Normal - Rugas Médias - Fototipo 3
Rugas - Pele Normal - Rugas Médias - Fototipo 4
(...)
```

Ou seja TODAS as combinações possíveis.

Comecei a fazer, mas não consegui evoluir:

```
foreach (var opcao in opcoes.Where(x => x.Categoria.Primeiro == true))
{
    // Pular Linha
    opcao.Nome //Exibir Opcao
    while(opcao.Ultima==false){
        // Pular Linha
    }


    proximaCategoria = opcao.CategoriaProxima;
    foreach(var proximaOpcao in opcoes.Where(x=>x.CategoriaProxima.Id == proximaCategoria.Id)){

    }
```

[VIEW]

```
@model IEnumerable<Dominio.Categoria>
@{
    var opcoes = ViewData["Opcoes"] as IEnumerable<Dominio.Opcao>;
}
<table>
    <thead>
       <tr>
        @foreach (var categoria in Model)
        {
            <th>
               @categoria.Nome
            </th>
         }
         </tr>
      </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var opcao in opcoes.Where(x=>x.Categoria.Primeiro == true)) {
            (...)
        }  
     </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

Vamos dar uma trabalhada nesse *Model* `Categoria`, colocando a propriedade inversa de opções:

```
public class Categoria
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public bool Primeiro { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Opcao> Opcoes { get; set; }
}
```

Eu faria duas funções, sendo uma recursiva:

```
public IEnumerable<String> MontarListaDeOpcoes(List<Categoria> categorias) 
{
    foreach (var categoria in categorias) 
    {
        foreach (var opcao in categoria.Opcoes) 
        {
            if (!opcao.Ultima)
            {
                yield return opcao.Nome + " - " + MontarListaDeOpcoes(opcao.CategoriaProxima);
            } else {
                yield return opcao.Nome;
            }
        }
    }
}

public IEnumerable<String> MontarListaDeOpcoes(Categoria categoria) 
{
    foreach (var opcao in categoria.Opcoes) 
    {
        if (!opcao.Ultima)
        {
            yield return opcao.Nome + " - " + MontarListaDeOpcoes(opcao.CategoriaProxima);
        } else {
            yield return opcao.Nome;
        }
    }
}
```

### View

```
@model IEnumerable<String>

<table>
    <thead>
       <tr>
            <th>
               Opções
            </th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var opcao in Model) 
        {
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @opcao
                </th>
             </tr>
        }  
     </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: E como eu faria para exibir isso em uma table, por exemplo?

Comment: @DiegoZanardo Coloca um pedaço da View que eu melhoro a resposta.

Comment: Adicionado Cigano!

Comment: @DiegoZanardo Atualizei a resposta. Não entendi bem como você quer construir essa tabela, mas acredito que trabalhando o código da resposta você chegue no resultado esperado.

Comment: T dando esse erro na assinatura do método, "cannot be an iterator block because List<string>' is not an iterator interface type"

Comment: @DiegoZanardo Foi mal! Verdade. `List` não pode ser devolvido por `yield`. Veja agora.

Comment: Agora tem outro erro rsrsrs, CategoriaProxima, é uma categoria e não uma lista de categoria... então ta dando erro no opcao.CategoriaProxima

Comment: Tentei ao inves de receber uma list de categorias, receber apenas uma categoria, mas sem sucesso!

Comment: @DiegoZanardo Escrevi esse código sem testar direito. Atualizei. Repare que fiz agora duas funções com polimorfismo pra que a chamada faça sentido.

Answer (score 1):

Uma outra forma de gerar esse arranjo seria utilizando o [SelectMany](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336(v=vs.100).ASPx).

Veja uma implementação:

```
// Não utilizei objeto criado por você para facilitar o exemplo.
var categoriaA = new[] { "Rugas","Manchas","Olheiras","Fotoproteção","Flacidez"};
var categoriaB = new[] { "Pele Normal","Pele Oleosa","Pele Seca","Pele Extra Seca"};
var categoriaC = new[] { "Rugas Finas","Rugas Médias","Rugas Profundas"};
var categoriaD = new[] { "Fototipo 1","Fototipo 2","Fototipo 3","Fototipo 4"};

// Escolhe todas as categorias, onde a ordem importa.
var arranjos =
    from a in categoriaA
    from b in categoriaB
    from c in categoriaC
    from d in categoriaD
    select new { a,b,c,d,Descricao = string.Format("{0} - {1} - {2} - {3}", a,b,c,d) };

ViewData["Opcoes"] = arranjos;
```

### View

```
<table>
    <thead>
       <tr>
            <th>a</th>
            <th>b</th>
            <th>c</th>
            <th>d</th>
            <th>Descrição</th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in ViewData["Opcoes"]) 
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@item.a</td>
                <td>@item.b</td>
                <td>@item.c</td>
                <td>@item.d</td>
                <td>@item.Descricao</td>
             </tr>
        }  
     </tbody>
</table>
```

A meu ver, você não precisaria das propriedades `Ultima`, `Proxima`, etc. se gerar o arranjo separado.

Comment: Mas existem opções que apontam para diferentes categorias. Por exemplo na categoria A a opção rugas pode apontar para a categoria C e as outras opções da categoria A apontem para a categoria B